# Which is the most suitable programming language for image processing in scientific researches?

Tags: image-processing

We are currently working on a platform (web application for a graduation final project we used mean stack) that able researchers to test default methods recognition (methods of Enhancement, Extraction, and matching ), add his own methods too (a script), compose a set of methods ( build a process of recognition) and visualize the outputs of each step. We want to know what a programming language is used the most for testing image processing in scientific articles.for the moment we are using Matlab for its simplicity.

Regards.

Comment: python. Matlab is good but lack of open libs if you want to scale your applications/simulations.

Comment: I'm sorry; while this definitely would be a fine topic for an evening discussion, it's too opinion-based and could only end up in a lot of controversial answers, but not a single definite answer. I'm closing this for being [too opinionated, subjective](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Welcome to SE.DSP!  I tend to agree with Marcus, but I'll let others vote on whether or not to close.  You can possibly re-word this to ask for pros and cons of staying with Matlab... but then I think it's more on-topic for SO itself rather than SE.DSP.

Comment: @PeterK. Thank you , i know it is an opinion question , i just didn't know where to get the information.

Comment: What do you mean by mean stack: http://mean.io/?

Comment: @LaurentDuval the Mongodb , Express , Angular and node , the stack of languages and frameworks used to develop the website.

Comment: Closed before I saw Peter's comment. Quick answer: What AlexTP said. Matlab probably shows up in papers more, Python is better for building systems.

Answer (score 3):

Your question as is has a very simple answer: "the best language is the one I use". Pros and Cons (P&C) would give some more value to it, as commented by Peter and Marcus. So, back to the topic, but concerning with P&C, here is my $\epsilon$...

Your application does not seem to be restrict only to simulation, but also to web interface; moreover, you want a roadmap to it, probably in a asynchronous way dealing with branches, and therefore with some version control.

Matlab can be a choice if your audience has all toolboxes you have for this work (web + image + signal + ... ). Does it?

Forget control versioning if you intend to use Simulink.

I would make thumbs up for Python as well. You have support of a huge community. The scientific packages are numerous. It is a complete language, from web applications to visual to scripting to ... And it is free!